# Summarizing boolean variables and their relationships

Tags: r, ggplot2, boolean, relationship

I would like to summarize boolean variables and their relationships. In particular:

1. For each variable I would like to count the number of TRUE.
2. For pair of variables I would like to count the the number of TRUE AND TRUE.

I have simulated some data to give you an example:

```
n <- 100
id <- 1:n

set.seed(1)
d1 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE)
d2 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE)
d3 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE)
d4 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE)
d5 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(id, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5)
```

Since after I will use the output to obtain a heatmap using `ggplot2`, I have find a solution based on the function `expand.grid` and the use of a `for`, but I would like to know if there is an alternative and more compact way to obtain such a result. I share my solution, including the code to obtain the heatmap (with no aesthetic tuning ;-) ).

```
library(ggplot)    
to_plot <- expand.grid(colnames(df)[-1], colnames(df)[-1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
to_plot$n <- NA

aux <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(to_plot)){
  
  aux <- aux + 1
  to_plot$n[aux] <- sum(df[to_plot$Var1[i]] & df[to_plot$Var2[i]])
  
}

ggplot(to_plot, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = n))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a bit less work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
to_plot <- expand.grid(colnames(df)[-1], colnames(df)[-1], 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
to_plot <- to_plot %>% 
  mutate(n = map2(Var1, Var2, ~sum(df[[.x]] & df[[.y]])))
```

---

Edit

In response to Ronak's answer avoiding the duplicate calculation, even thought it seems that way should always be faster, it is not.  Consider the following set of benchmarks.  First, here are the two operations we're doing:

```
op1 <- function(){
  cols <- names(df)[-1]
  val <- combn(cols, 2, function(x) sum(rowSums(df[x]) == 2))
  mat <- matrix(nrow = length(cols), ncol = length(cols),
                dimnames = list(cols, cols))
  mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- val
  mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- val
  diag(mat) <- colSums(df[-1])
  
  out <- mat %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column('row') %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -row) 
}

op2 <- function(){
  to_plot <- expand.grid(colnames(df)[-1], colnames(df)[-1], 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  to_plot <- to_plot %>% 
    mutate(n = map2(Var1, Var2, ~sum(df[[.x]] & df[[.y]])))
}
```

In the original setup with 5 variables and 100 observations, set up the data:

```
n <- 100
nvar <- 5
id <- 1:n

dat <- lapply(1:nvar, function(i)sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE))
names(dat) <- paste0("d", seq_along(dat))
df <- do.call(data.frame, dat)
df <- cbind(id=id, df)
```

Run the benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark(op1(), op2(), times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 op1() 4.002038 4.551332 6.633587 5.499613 8.341939 12.335900   100   b
 op2() 1.200123 1.323183 2.011996 1.743236 2.305946  4.030759   100  a
```

When there are 100 variables each with 1000 observations:

```
n <- 1000
nvar <- 100
id <- 1:n

dat <- lapply(1:nvar, function(i)sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE))
names(dat) <- paste("d", seq_along(dat))
dat$id <- id
df <- do.call(data.frame, dat)
```

Run the benchmarks:

```
microbenchmark(op1(), op2(), times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 op1() 332.0568 352.9815 377.0784 369.1204 383.3933 768.0261   100   b
 op2() 158.8863 170.4160 185.8864 184.4045 198.0373 254.2080   100  a
```

In both cases, the operation that does more calculation is actually substantially faster.  This obviously will not make a perceptible difference in small data, but it is interesting to see how different operations scale.

Comment: Luckly you didn't consider my for-based solution in the competion, lol! I like a lot your approach based on expand.grid+map2. However, I will keep open the question for few days more just in case somebody knows a even more compact way to perform this task. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't short but it avoid recalculating stuff because `d1`, `d2` value is same as `d2`, `d1`. We can calculate it only once and update it at two places. Also it avoids calculation of `d1` and `d1` using `colSums`.

Using `combn` :

```
library(tidyverse)

cols <- names(df)[-1]
val <- combn(cols, 2, function(x) sum(rowSums(df[x]) == 2))
mat <- matrix(nrow = length(cols), ncol = length(cols),
              dimnames = list(cols, cols))
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- val
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- val
diag(mat) <- colSums(df[-1])

mat %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column('row') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  ggplot(aes(row, name)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value))
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer and when I first looked at the problem, I had used `combn` as well, though to be honest, not as well as you did.  However, I thought it would be neat to look at the benchmarks, so I edited my answer below to include them.  Surprisingly, the operation that duplicates the calculations is actually faster.